# ¿Cómo definir tamaño de recorte por defecto en una imagen usando Jcrop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Espero me puedan orientar, he estado intentando que inicie por defecto el tamaño de selección de recorte 400x400 px de una imagen usando Jcrop, pero no logro hacer que el área de recorte inicie y se quede en 400x400 px, he estado buscando pero no logro realizarlo espero me orienten soy nuevo en js, esto es lo que llevo. Lo que busco es que ya se inicie el área de recorte por default de tamaño 400px x 400 px. Y solo se seleccione en que coordenadas quiere el usuario recortar la imagen, un saludo muchas gracias.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
            var size;
            $('#RecortarImagen').Jcrop({
              aspectRatio: 1,
              onSelect: function(c){
               size = {x:c.x,y:c.y,w:c.w,h:c.h};
               $("#recortar").css("visibility", "visible");     
               $("#descargar").css("visibility", "visible");     
              }
            });
         
            $("#recortar").click(function(){
                var img = $("#RecortarImagen").attr('src');
                $("#imgrecortada_img").show();
                $("#descargar").show();
                $("#imgrecortada_img").attr('src','ImagenRecortada.php?x='+size.x+'&y='+size.y+'&w='+size.w+'&h='+size.h+'&img='+img);
            });
      });
    </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

size = {x:c.x,y:c.y,w:'400',h:'400'};

Comment: Hola, es necesario explicar la respuesta para que la información sirva a otras personas que pudieran tener problemas similares, te recomiendo leer [Cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: ¿Qué hemos aprendido? Nada. ¿Qué utilidad tiene para otras personas? Ninguna. ¿Debe ocupar espacio en este sitio? No.